# How can I use brackets while using bc (Unix basic calculator)?

Tags: linux, unix, windows-subsystem-for-linux, bc

While working with `bc`, UNIX basic calculator on my Ubuntu WSL, I found this bizarre behaviour:

```
Prompt> echo (1+2)*3 | bc -l
-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `1+2'
Prompt> echo (1 + 2) * 3 | bc -l
-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `1'
```

At first, I thought this meant that `bc` does not cover brackets, but then I did this:

```
Prompt> bc
bc 1.07.1
Copyright 1991-1994, 1997, 1998, 2000, 2004, 2006, 2008, 2012-2017 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY.
For details type `warranty'.
(1 + 2) * 3
9
(1+2)*3
9
^C
(interrupt) use quit to exit.
quit
```

So `bc` does support the usage of brackets.

Does anybody know how I can use arithmetic expressions with brackets, while using `bc` as a one-liner-support-tool (I mean, while using it in one-liners like (`...| bc`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use quotes around your expression, such as:

`echo "(1 + 2) * 3" | bc -l`